# How to add column names to the existing csv

Tags: r

I want to do some analysis on an existing CSV file. However, Since the original file doesn't have a header, the Rstudio automatically set the first row as the header. Since some of the elements in the first row appear in the rest of the code, I couldn't just replace them and append a new record. Could anyone help me with this, please?

This the code.

```
adultdata <- read.csv("adultdata.csv",head=T,sep=',',fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

adultdata

```
X39       State.gov     X77516   Bachelors   X13    Never.married
<int>     <fctr>         <int>    <fctr>     <int>  <fctr>
50  Self-emp-not-inc    83311    Bachelors   13     Married
38  Private             215646   HS-grad     9      Divorced
53  Private             234721   11th        7      Married
```

What I wanna get is something like this

```
age     workclass         fnlwgt    education   education-num  marital-status
39      State.gov         77516     Bachelors   13             Never.married
50      Self-emp-not-inc  83311     Bachelors   13             Married
38    Private             215646    HS-grad     9              Divorced
53    Private             234721    11th        7              Married
```

Comment: Since the data file does not have a header, it is a bad idea to use `head=T`.  I recommend using `header=F`

Comment: Use `setNames`.

Comment: In addition to G5W's suggestion, it is better to specify as TRUE/FALSE instead of `T/F` as  TRUE/FALSE are reserved words while `T/F` can be assigned as identifiers to objects (`T <- 1;
TRUE <- 1`)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced minus `-` with underscore `_`.

Best,
Tyler

```
read.csv(
  file = "adultdata.csv", 
  header = F, 
  col.names = c("age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education_num", "marital_status"))
```